# ReadKey needs input twice

Tags: c#, console-application

```
public static void readkey()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();

    switch(input.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D9:
             Console.Clear();
             Console.WriteLine("U heeft het programma succesvol afgesloten!");
             Console.Read();
             Environment.Exit(0);
        break;

        case ConsoleKey.D1:
             overzichtmp();
        break;

        case ConsoleKey.D2:
             overzichtvr();
        break;

        default:
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Voer een geldig nummer in!");
            Console.Read();
            showmenu();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I press a key the first time it flashes to the method and directly back and the second time it just starts normal any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? You can use the debugger to step through the code line by line and see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Yes but I cant figure out what is causing it

Comment: I think `Console.Read` expecting second input.

Comment: But you can at least tell us which key you press, and which case it falls into. Could it not be a bug in overzichtmp or overzichtvr ?

Comment: Script99, if you use the [Visual Studio debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) to step through the code, I think you'll see that the Console.Read() call in your default cause is what's causing this, as @Selman22 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the below is what you are looking for, but it sets up the program loop to call your readkey and eliminates the 2nd Console.Read and replaces it with a sleep wait.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        readkey();
    }
}

public static void readkey()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();

    switch(input.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D9:
             Console.Clear();
             Console.WriteLine("U heeft het programma succesvol afgesloten!");
             //You might want to wait:  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
             Environment.Exit(0);
        break;

        case ConsoleKey.D1:
             overzichtmp();
        break;

        case ConsoleKey.D2:
             overzichtvr();
        break;

        default:
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Voer een geldig nummer in!");
            // possibly add the wait here as well
            showmenu();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```